# actionStatus not working without reRender?

Tags: actionsupport, actionstatus

I would want to ask you, if it's possible, the actionStatus to be triggered without the attribute rerender on actionSupport?
Example:

```
<apex:inputFile id="file_test" value="{!att.Body}" filename="{!att.Name}" rendered="{!showFile}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!upload}" status="loadingstatus" reRender="loadingstatus"/>
                    <apex:actionStatus id="loadingstatus">
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                             <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.loading)}" />
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
```

In this case, the acionStatus is working, but if I delete the reRender attribute on actionSupport, then it's not working. I don't want to use reRender, because inputFile is not working in conjunction with rerender attribute :)

Comment: The actionstatus tag is designed to show a status message while re-rendering. It will not work without a rerender.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I've used the following as a workaround....

```
<apex:inputFile />
<apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" onclick="document.getElementById('LoaderImg').style.display = 'show';"/>
<img id="LoaderImg" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.loading)}" style="display:none;"/>
```